# renv error Warning: Error in loadNamespace: namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required

Tags: r, renv

I am using Rshiny and renv packages, got this issue. How shall I resolve it?

Warning: Error in loadNamespace: namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required

Comment: Restart R, reinstall the package. — This question has been asked zillions of times, but unfortunately the existing answers are not great since they are overly specific. (Edit: ah, found a good duplicate)

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is not the same when using renv package. My question was about this issue when renv package is controlling which packages are installed

Comment: I am not convinced that this isn’t the same issue, and you need to edit your question to add more details (when exactly are you getting this error, etc.) but let’s see if somebody can answer it.